# ggplot: plot time series with repeating time values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data over hours that looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame('hour' = rep(0:23, 2),
                 'mean' = rnorm(48),
                 'sd' = rnorm(48))
```

I wish to plot `geom_smooth()` over the entire period:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = hour)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = sd))
```

However, by default my `hour` parameter is being factored such that every hour only appears once, as can be seen if one adds `geom_point()`, but I want all 48 (many more in reality) values to appear on my x axis.
I realize there must be a single argument I'm missing but can't find.

Comment: If your data is already summarized at `hour` level, you won't be able to do it. You should have your data in a melted state for ggplot.

Comment: @csgroen but it is not summarized at hour level, on the contrary. Every hour appears multiple times in the data on purpose. Do you mean I should extend the time, to include a date, for example?

Comment: Oh sorry, your example here is summarized at hour level, so I assumed. I'm slightly confused as to your intended output. Do you want a point for each hour on your plot? If yes, then you can do a geom_point (or geom_jitter for many overlapping points).

Comment: The purpose of geom_smooth is to summarise data, so I'm not really sure that you're reaching for the right geom_* for what you're hoping to generate. Can you describe the plot you're hoping for?

Comment: I'am not sure if I understand your question. If I add geom_point() I see two points for each hour.

Comment: @JayAchar I want the line in `geom_smooth` to represents the means (which is also achievable with `geom_lines`) but I want the cloud to be based off of `sd`, and so this should be for each data point over several days (as described by 24 hour cycles in the data).

Comment: It's like as if I gave the lines indices and went with that, but just... without doing that. Is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: @ricoderks I understand these functions summarize the data by default, I want to know if there is a way to not do that and just plot every data point separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the hour you use as a date_time object, where the hours in the second halve are on the next day

You may use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(9876) # for reproducibility
df <- data.frame('hour' = seq(c(ISOdate(2019,12,1)), by = "hour", length.out = 48),
                 'mean' = rnorm(48),
                 'sd' = rnorm(48))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = hour)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = sd))
```

Please, let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately my data is already set and not made by me, so I can't change the hours, I don't know what the date was. But this did give me an idea to just give the rows indices which works fine, and then add the ribbon separately with `geom_ribbon`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the line of geom_smooth to represent the mean column in your data frame, and the error ribbon to represent the sd column.

I believe this should give the output you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = hour)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = sd), fun.data = mean_se, geom="ribbon", alpha=0.25)
```

Comment: I've explained in the comments that my main issue is the fact that `smooth` summarizes the data by x axis values, whereas I don't want my data summarized, I want the x values repeating because it's a time series. You solution is good but is a solution for a different question. :)